# Can I access a class variable with another variable?

Tags: c#, class, variables, reflection

i want to do a class constructor that takes a dicionary as parameter and initialize all the class variables that are listed as key in the dictionary, after of course a type conversion:

```cs
public class User
    {   
        public int id;
        public string username;
        public string password;
        public string email;
        public int mana_fire;
        public int mana_water;
        public int mana_earth;
        public int mana_life;
        public int mana_death;

        public User ()
        {
        }
        public User(Dictionary<string,string> dataArray){
            FieldInfo[] classVariablesInfoList  = typeof(User).GetFields();
            for(int i = 0; i < classVariablesInfoList.Length; i++)
            {
                if(dataArray.ContainsKey(classVariablesInfoList[i].Name)){
                    //missing code here :)
                                    //need something like classVariable= dataArray["classVariablesInfolist[i].name"]; ?


                }
            }
        }

    }
```

but i can't find out how to do this!
Can you please help? :)

Comment: You can do that. but why? Why don't you just access the field directly with all required parameters defined in constructor.

Comment: You can achieve that using reflection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965635/c-sharp-reflection-changing-the-value-of-a-field-of-a-variable

Comment: i would like to have a contructor that does not need to be updated when class variables definition changes

Comment: That gives you a constructor which doesn't change even when fields added. but don't forget that it will not help you when invalid field name is passed in dictionary(can happen when you change the field names).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SetValue frunction from reflection:

```
FieldInfo f = classVariablesInfoList[i];
if (f.ReflectedType == typeof(int))
{
    f.SetValue(this, Convert.ToInt32(dataArray[f.Name]));
}
else
{
    f.SetValue(this, dataArray[classVariablesInfoList[i].Name]);
}
```

But it is a really uncommon way to do this with a dictionary. You should considder accessing the fields directly or add parameters to the constructor for any field. And fields should never be public - use properties instead.

Comment: This will not work because the dictionary contains only strings but some of the fields are of other types. You have to incorporate some kind of type conversion and this might get ugly in the general case.

Comment: what if f? can i do type conversion in here?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to separate your problem into two parts.

## 1. Applying conversion

The FieldInfo type present a `FieldType` property that is the actual type of the field, using this `Type` we can use the non-generic [ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of `System.Convert`, this method will be able convert some types to others. Luckily it support `String to Int`.
Usage:

```
Convert.ChangeType(OLD_VALUE, TARGET_TYPE);
```

## 2. Setting the field

The field info class has a `SetValue` method ([FieldInfo.SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z33zd7h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), it has two parameters, the first one is the current (ie. this) instance (or the instance you wish to change). the second is the new value you wish to set.

## Putting it all together

```
[...]
var fieldInfo = classVariablesInfoList[i];
var name = fieldInfo.Name;
var targetType = fieldInfo.Type;
var value = Convert.ChangeType(dataArray[name], targetType);
classVariablesInfoList[i].SetValue(this, value);
```

Comment: This will not work because the dictionary contains only strings but some of the fields are of other types. You have to incorporate some kind of type conversion and this might get ugly in the general case.

Comment: @DanielBrückner Oh right, I'm so used to this kind of type initialization using object so I didn't notice.

Comment: You have the arguments to `Convert.ChangeType()` in the wrong order.

Comment: @DanielBrückner Thanks, at least I got it right the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work if [`Convert.ChangeType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) is able to handle the conversion. There are a lot of problems waiting to occur, for example handling numbers or dates where the string representation depends on the locale. I would really suggest to use usual typed constructor parameters or standard [(de)serialization mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9.aspx) if possible. Or at least use a dictionary containing objects instead of strings to get rid of the conversion, again if possible.

```
public User(Dictionary<String, String> data)
{
   var fields = typeof(User).GetFields();

   foreach (field in fields)
   {
      if (data.ContainsKey(field.Name))
      {
         var value = Convert.ChangeType(data[field.Name], field.MemberType);

         field.SetValue(this, value);
      }
   }
}
```