# Get / Set private variables from base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, xna

```
Class GameObject
{
     private Vector2 position

     public Vector2 Position
     {
        get { return position; }
        set { position = value; }
     }
}
```

Above is my base class, I would like to change the position value within my inherited class but I cannot seem to access the variable. Below is my inherited class

```
Class Enemy : GameObject
{
      public void MoveRight()
      {
            //I want to change the value of position here but cannot access the variable
            position.X += 1.0f; 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to access the variable?  Just update the Property value:

```
class Enemy : GameObject
{
      public void MoveRight()
      {
            //I want to change the value of position here but cannot access the variable
            this.Position.X += 1.0f; 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: Elevate the private member to protected.

```
Class GameObject
{
     protected Vector2 position

     public Vector2 Position
     {
        get { return position; }
        set { position = value; }
     }
}
```

Protected members are like private members that are also accessible by derived types.

Solution 2: Access the member through the property like suggested by Mike.

Solution 3: Use [reflection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965635/c-sharp-reflection-changing-the-value-of-a-field-of-a-variable) (Not what you need, but fyi. Never kill a fly with a shotgun)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access "position" because you declared it as PRIVATE. It is accessible ONLY in the class where it was declared.

Change to PROTECTED if you want to make it accessible to derived classes.

This way it will not be visible outside the class, but the derived classes will be able to see it and use it.

**Edit**

But if you will do nothing in the "Position" member set/get, than you can just use an auto-property:

```
public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
```

And forget about the field.
In any case, don't forget that "position" or "Postion" must be initialized before used.

Comment: Technically the last comment isn't 100% correct. Vector2 is a Struct, so it will have a default value of 0,0 since it's not in method scope. Just FYI

Comment: Thanks @BjarkeSøgaard, I didn't know that Vector2 was a struct. :)

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for similar and this should be the answer
In your Base (parrent) Class type for example:

```
public bool Connected { get; protected set; } = false;
```

protected allows for a derived classes to set the value.
While they're not writeable outside the derived (child) class only readable.
While inside the child class you can set them.